# Executing a pipeline only after another one finishes on google dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to run a pipeline on google dataflow that depends on the output of another pipeline. Right now I am just running two pipelines after each other with the DirectRunner locally:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    (p
     | beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input)
     | SomeTransform()
     | beam.io.WriteToText('temp'))

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    (p
     | beam.io.ReadFromText('temp*')
     | AnotherTransform()
     | beam.io.WriteToText(known_args.output))
```

My questions are the following:

- Does the DataflowRunner guarantee that the second is only started after the first pipeline completed?
- Is there a preferred method to run two pipelines consequetively after each other?
- Also is there a recommended way to separate those pipelines into different files in order to test them better?

Answer (score 3):

> Does the DataflowRunner guarantee that the second is only started after the first pipeline completed?

No, Dataflow simply executes a pipeline. It has no features for managing dependent pipeline executions.

**Update**: For clarification, Apache Beam does provide a mechanism for waiting for a pipeline to complete execution. See the `waitUntilFinish()` method of the `PipelineResult` class. Reference: [PipelineResult.waitUntilFinish()](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/PipelineResult.html#waitUntilFinish--).

> Is there a preferred method to run two pipelines consequetively after each other?

Consider using a tool like Apache Airflow for managing dependent pipelines. You can even implement a simple bash script to deploy one pipeline after another one has finished.

> Also is there a recommended way to separate those pipelines into different files in order to test them better?

Yes, separate files. This is just good code organization, not necessarily better for testing.

Comment: Your first point is not fully correct. It is true that Dataflow per se doesn't manage pipeline dependencies, but it certainly provides an API to wait for a pipeline to finish, and the "with" statement on the Pipeline object uses that API.

Comment: @jkff, yes, that's correct. The `PipelineResult` class in the Apache Beam Java SDK has a method `waitUntilFinish()`.

Comment: what about python?